# cocos2d Scene goes black after GameCenter leaderboard dismissal

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

Im having a strange problem that only occurs on the iPad version of my game. When I bring up the GameCenter leaderboard, it appears like normal. No issues there. But when you tap the close button the leader board disappears and the cocos2d scene goes black. No errors, nothing. Nothing I do can bring the screen back. Ive tried resuming the director and even tried some solutions on a similar thread.

Here is my code in the cocos2d scene. GCController is just a subclass of the RootViewController, nothing special:

```
tempVC = [[GCController alloc] init];

GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController   alloc] init] autorelease];

if (leaderboardController != nil)
{
    leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
    leaderboardController.category = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self  cleanString:selectedSong], @"TotalHD"];
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:tempVC.view];
    [tempVC presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
}

- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    [tempVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [tempVC.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
    [tempVC release];
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? If I can provide any more information let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing enough code.  I see no fault in the code you are showing at the moment.  Your most likely cause of a black screen (depending on how you do things) is that timers have been interrupted and you may need to reset them with

```
- (void) onEnter;
```

or

```
- (void) onEnterTransitionDidFinish;
```

If that isn't it then post more code and I will check back.  We need to see when the view is presented and what it should return to.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    [tempVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

> ```
>     **[tempVC.view removeFromSuperview];**
> ```

```
}
```

Comment: code describe above means in question i did change only on statement temvc.view.Superview into tempvc.view